# Error of file duplication when i try to build my project

Tags: ios, json

Please i have this error when i try to build my project :

```
duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in /Users/imac/libs/CloudMade/libCloudMadeApi.a(SBJsonBase.o) and /Users/imac/Desktop/TopStation/build/TopStation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopStation.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonBase.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I dont really know anything about JSON, but this sprang up on google as the first result when doing a search for "json duplicate symbol"

http://www.dizzey.com/development/ios/duplicate-symbols-when-linking-objectivec-static-libraries/

As far as I can tell, it touches on your exact problem.